# How to get all tweets for a given topic using GetOldTweets3 while handling HTTP request: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests

Tags: python, twitter

I'm trying to get all tweets from a single day using the GetOldTweets3 package. However, I am getting an HTTPRequest error 429: Too Many requests if the number of pulls exceeds 10000. Is there a way to make my application sleep to overcome the Twitter rate limit and resume again from where I was?
I appreciate the help.

Below is the code I am running.

```
import pandas as pd
import GetOldTweets3 as got

def get_tweets(top_only, topic, start_date, end_date):
    tweetCriteria = got.manager.TweetCriteria().setTopTweets(top_only).setQuerySearch(topic)\
        .setSince(start_date) \
        .setUntil(end_date).setMaxTweets(20000)

    tweet = got.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweetCriteria)
    tweet_list = [[tw.username,tw.text,tw.date,tw.retweets,tw.favorites,tw.mentions,tw.hashtags]
                  for tw in tweet]

    tweet_df = pd.DataFrame(tweet_list, columns = ['Username','Text','Date','Favorites','Retweets',
                                                   'Mentions','Hashtags'])

    return tweet_df

topics = 'coronavirus'
tweet_df = get_tweets(top_only=True, topic=topics, start_date='2020-03-10', end_date = '2020-03-11')\
    .sort_values('Date', ascending = False)
```

Comment: You should be able to check the response header for x-rate-limit-remaining to let you know how many requests you have left in the current window and also x-rate-limit-reset to know how many seconds before the limit resets.

By combining those, you can either spread out the calls, or once you reach the limit, sleep for the number of seconds remaining until the reset.

Comment: @PETER STACEY  Can you please suggest how to check for response header using getOldtweets3?